# How do I hide an article if it doesn't have an image?

Tags: 7, views

How do I hide an article if it doesn't have an image?

In Drupal 6, the setting is *Block: Configure filter Content: (field_image)*, but I can't find this settings in Drupal 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a condition on view filter. If image field is empty then row will not display.

> Content: field_image:fid (not empty)

OR

> Content: Slide image:fid (!= 0)